# react-google-maps TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'setZoom'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps-api-3, react-google-maps

I am using the `react-google-maps` package in my app. I want to access the Map.setZoom() method but I am getting

> TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'setZoom'

Interestingly, the `Map.panTo()` method works just fine. They should both be members of the Map object.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3.exp/map#Map.panTo
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3.exp/map#Map.setZoom

```
withHandlers(() => {
    const refs = {
      map: undefined
    }

    return {
      onMapMounted: () => ref => {
        refs.map = ref
      },

      onClick: () => () => {
        console.log("Getting location...");
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
          position => {
            const coords = {
              lat: position.coords.latitude,
              lng: position.coords.longitude
            };
            console.log(coords);
            refs.map.panTo(coords);   // This line works
            refs.map.setZoom(8);      // This line throws a Type Error
          },
          error => {
            console.log("Error" + error.code);
          }
        );
      }
    }
  }),
...
```

Here is my entire component definition, loosely based on the `react-google-maps` documentation https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps/#googlemap

```
const Map = compose(
  withProps({
    googleMapURL: `${url}`,
    loadingElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
    containerElement: <div style={{ height: `400px` }} />,
    mapElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
  }),
  withHandlers(() => {
    const refs = {
      map: undefined
    }

    return {
      onMapMounted: () => ref => {
        refs.map = ref
      },

      onClick: () => () => {
        console.log("Getting location...");
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
          position => {
            const coords = {
              lat: position.coords.latitude,
              lng: position.coords.longitude
            };
            console.log(coords);
            refs.map.panTo(coords);
            refs.map.setZoom(8);
          },
          error => {
            console.log("Error" + error.code);
          }
        );
      }
    }
  }),
  withScriptjs,
  withGoogleMap
)((props) =>
  <GoogleMap
    defaultZoom={4}
    defaultCenter={DefaultCoords}
    ref={props.onMapMounted}
  >
    <OverlayView
      position={DefaultCoords}
      mapPaneName={OverlayView.OVERLAY_MOUSE_TARGET}
      getPixelPositionOffset={getPixelPositionOffset}
    >
      <div style={{ background: `white`, border: `1px solid #ccc`, padding: 15 }}>
        <button onClick={props.onClick}>Use GPS</button>
      </div>
    </OverlayView>
    {props.isMarkerShown && <Marker position={DefaultCoords} />}
  </GoogleMap>
);
```

Comment: There seems to be no `setZoom` method [according to the documentation](https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps/#usage--configuration).

Comment: There is one https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3.exp/map#Map.setZoom. Unless I'm grossly misunderstanding something.

Comment: You're right in that it exists on a regular Google map, but not on a `react-google-map` component. [There doesn't seem to be a method on that component for setting zoom in the same way there is for panning](https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps/blob/ca5c5c6f5346fb3ee0037893fbca488a408c9938/src/components/GoogleMap.jsx#L231-L237).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed [`GoogleMap` class](https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps/#googlemap) of `react-google-maps` library does not expose `setZoom` method yet.

One solution would be to access `google.maps.Map` class directly and set zoom as demonstrated below:

1) get access to `google.maps.Map` instance:

```
 onMapMounted: () => ref  => {
    refs.map = ref
    refs.mapObject = ref.context[MAP];  //<-access google.maps.Map instance
 }
```

2) where `MAP` is a constant from:

`import {MAP} from 'react-google-maps/lib/constants'`

3) set zoom:

```
 refs.mapObject.setZoom(8);
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-crnrko)